# NSMutableArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock is not synchronous as Apple says

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, enumeration

Is this a bug?

I have this lines:

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

     NSLog(@"%d", idx);
}];

NSLog(@"end");
```

This should print like this

```
"0"
"1"
"2"
...
"end"
```

but it is printing like

```
"end"
"0"
"1"
"2"
...
```

Apple says `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` is synchronous, so "end" should not be printed before the enumeration, right?

Can you guys confirm?

Comment: are you using `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` or `enumerateObjectsusingBlock:`... if you're using withOptions, what options are you specifying?

Comment: It has been my experience as well that enumerateObjectsusingBlock: is not ordered (order differs each call), so am too looking for confirmation.

Comment: @L14M333 - does not matter, Apple says both are synchronous. BTW I have tried both.

Comment: Please put a sample project on GitHub which reproduces this issue. Any trivial test of the code above prints the correct output, so there is something missing from your question. If you can reproduce it, you'll need a sample project to send to Apple when filing a radar.

Comment: @RubberDuck Just wanted to tell you that I have experienced the same issue working in my own code. It has also happened to one colleague just today. So there is an issue here, that's for sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` is definitely synchronous. I just ran the same example in CodeRunner:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ @1, @2, @3, @4, @5 ];
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%d", idx);
}];

NSLog(@"end");
```

And got the following output:

```
0
1
2
3 
4
end
```

Comment: this is weird as hell, because mine is not... 

Comment: You're not printing `end` anywhere before your enumeration? Are you using `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` (as mentioned at the bottom of your question) instead of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`?

Comment: nope. END is being printed after the enumeration. I have tried both methods. No change.

Comment: thats how it should be?

Comment: "End is being printed *after* the enumeration" - that's what you want, isn't it?

Comment: @RubberDuck Did you ever work out what was happening?

Comment: nope, I just started a new project, copied everything to that project and it worked... don't ask me why.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot confirm this, it's printing as expected: "0","1","2","End". Also notice that you are printing indexes but your log starts at "1".

Comment: Is it printing correctly for you??????????? I have fixed the 0,1,2 part... just a typo.

Comment: you can test as i have posted above answer