# Add completion block to enumerateObjectsWithOptions

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, enumeration

I need to perform an action after the complete enumeration of all the objects in an array. How can I add a completion block to `enumerateObjectsWithOptions(_:usingBlock:)` in Swift.

Or how to know when `enumerateObjectsWithOptions(_:usingBlock:)` has completed.

```
allVisitors.enumerateObjectsWithOptions( NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent, usingBlock: { (obj, idx, stop) -> Void in
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Method enumerateObjectsWithOptions in NSArray is [synchronous](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:).

So what you write on the next line will be executed after your block has been executed for every element in the array. [These users tested the version without options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256372/nsmutablearray-enumerateobjectsusingblock-is-not-synchronous-as-apple-says).

E.g.

```
allVisitors.enumerateObjectsWithOptions( NSEnumerationOptions.Concurrent, usingBlock: { (obj, idx, stop) -> Void in
    // do your stuff
})

println("now allVisitors.enumerateObjectsWithOptions has done")
```

Answer (score 1):

The method: `enumerateObjectsWithOptions(_:usingBlock:)`  is synchronous.

> By default, the enumeration starts with the first object and continues
>   serially through the array to the last object. You can specify
>   NSEnumerationConcurrent and/or NSEnumerationReverse as enumeration
>   options to modify this behavior. This method executes synchronously.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:

So, you don't need to add a completion block to know when finishes, just write what you want to execute below  `enumerateObjectsWithOptions(_:usingBlock:)`

If you want, I can try to help you to add a block at the end, but I think it not make sense.